# Zend random salt generation for element_hash

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using the following hash with a salt that says `'unique'`. I'm not sure if `'unique'` is a literal string or an internal zend keyword for Zend to actually generate a unique salt?

If it's just a random string I think it's better to change that, so does zend have a random string generation function that could be used to salt this sort of hash element?

```
$hash = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('hash', 'no_csrf_foo', array('salt' => 'unique'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation on line specifying it as a keyword so i looked at the code

http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/~raw,r=20291/Zend_Framework/standard/branches/release-1.10/library/Zend/Form/Element/Hash.php

Looking at the code, i would say no unique is not a keyword, they are telling you to give it a unique salt.